# Showing a list of polynomials is linearly dependent in $\mathcal{P}_m(\mathbb{F})$

Tags: polynomials, proof-writing

**Note:** In case the notation isn't common, $\mathcal{P}_m(\mathbb{F})$ denotes the set of all polynomials $\mathbb{F} \to \mathbb{F}$ with at most degree $m$.

I'm having trouble with the following question:

> Suppose $p_0, p_1, \dots, p_m$ are polynomials in $\mathcal{P}_m(\mathbb{F})$ such that $p_j(2)=0$ for each $j$. Prove that $p_0, p_1, \dots, p_m$ are not linearly independent.

**Attempt:** Assume the list of polynomials is linearly indepedent. Then the only choice of $a_i \in \mathbb{F}$ such that 
$$a_0p_0(z) + a_1p_1(z)+ \cdots + a_mp_m(z)=0$$
is $a_i=0$ for all $0\leq i \leq m$, for all $z\in \mathbb{F}$. But note
$$a_0p_0(2)+\cdots + a_mp_m(2)=a_0(0)+\cdots a_m(0)=0$$
thus...

---

I feel like I'm definitely misunderstanding polynomials here. I'm tempted to say something along the lines of, "since now we can pick any $a_i \in \mathbb{F}$, not all $0$, and achieve $a_0p_0(z)+\cdots + a_mp_m(z)=0$ for some particular $z \in \mathbb{F}$, then the list is linearly dependent". But to show linear dependence here, do I need $a_i \in \mathbb{F}$, not all $0$, such that $a_0p_0(z)+\cdots + a_mp_m(z)=0$ *for all* $z \in \mathbb{F}$ *or for **at least one*** $z \in \mathbb{F}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that since you have $m+1$ polynomial, lineal independence would in particular imply that $<p_0,...,p_m>$ generates $\mathbb{F}_{\leq m}$. However, this is not so: clearly

$$
<p_0, \dots p_m> \subseteq \{p \in \mathbb{F}_{\leq m} : p(2) = 0\}
$$

which is a proper subspace of $\mathbb{F}_{\leq m}$ since, for example, it does not contain 1. In general you could have linearly independent polynomials that behave like this, as long as they are not 'too many'. Take for example $(X-2)X$ and $(X-2)X^2$ in $\mathbb{R}_{\leq 3}$, they both verify the former property but they are linearly independent, because  they have different degrees. We have then constructed a linearly independent set of polynomials that vanishes at $2$.

In general, for any vector space, proving that $v_1, \dots v_n$ are linearly independent consist of showing the following implication

$$
\sum_{i=1}^na_iv_i = 0 \ \Rightarrow a_i = 0 \ (\forall i)
$$

In this particular scenario, the first equality to zero means the zero polynomial, that is, the one whose coefficients are all zero (this shouldn't be confused with $p(z) = 0 \ (\forall z)$, think for example of $X(X-1)$ in $\mathbb{Z}_2$).

Comment: Ahhh, great idea in noticing that it doesn't contain $1$! This definitely is enough to solve the problem, thank you for contributing this answer. I'd still really like to know the answer though to the confusion at the end of my post, if it's not too much trouble.

Comment: I've edited the answer to give a bit more insight. You're right in having the intution that this is not enough to prove linear independence, because indeed it is not enough in most cases. We're making a very strong use of the amount of polynomials. I hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I am reading "Linear Algebra Done Right 3rd Edition" by Sheldon Axler.

This book contains the following problem. (Exercise 2.A 16 on p.38)

> Suppose $p_0, p_1, \dots, p_m$ are polynomials in $\mathcal{P}_m(\mathbb{F})$ such that $p_j(2)=0$ for each $j$. Prove that $p_0, p_1, \dots, p_m$ is not linearly independent in $\mathcal{P}_m(\mathbb{F})$.

My answer is here:

> If $m=0$, $p_0$ is a constant function and $p_0(2)=0$.
> So, $p_0$ is the zero function from $\mathbb{F}$ to $\mathbb{F}$.
> So, $p_0$ is not linearly independent in $\mathcal{P}_0(\mathbb{F})$.
> Suppose that $m\geq1$.
> We can write $p_j(x)=(x-2)q_j(x)$ for any $x\in\mathbb{F}$, where $q_j\in\mathcal{P}_{m-1}(\mathbb{F})$ for each $j\in\{0,\dots,m\}$.
> Since $\text{Span}(1,x,\dots,x^{m-1})=\mathcal{P}_{m-1}(\mathbb{F})$, $q_0,\dots,q_m$ is linearly dependent by 2.23 on p.35 in "Linear Algebra Done Right 3rd Edition" by Sheldon Axler.
> So, there exist numbers $a_0,\dots,a_m\in\mathbb{F}$, not all $0$, such that $a_0 q_0(x)+\cdots+a_m q_m(x)=0$ for any $x\in\mathbb{F}$.
> Obviously, $(x-2)(a_0 q_0(x)+\cdots+a_m q_m(x))=0$ for any $x\in\mathbb{F}$.
> So, $a_0 (x-2) q_0(x)+\cdots+a_m (x-2) q_m(x)=0$ for any $x\in\mathbb{F}$.
> So, $a_0 p_0(x)+\cdots+a_m p_m(x)=0$ for any $x\in\mathbb{F}$.
> So, $p_0,p_1,\dots,p_m$ is not linearly independent in $\mathcal{P}_m(\mathbb{F})$.